# How to return total entries found from html5 database?

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite

Hi I am trying to return the length of no. of rows found in the database but i am getting undefined. Is their any other way I can return since I am a bit new to jquery.

```
var add_access_db = {"add_access" : function(id, table)                                             //get id of equipment 
    {    
            db.transaction(function (tx) { 

            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+ table +' WHERE id=? AND Access=?', [id,"0"],            //Check access (table is the table name passed though variable)
            function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;                                                       //Get row length for access
            return len;

            });
        });
    }
}
```

and i am calling it through

```
function checkDetails(){
    var len=add_access_db.add_access(id, table);            //check access
    alert(len);
}
```

What am I doing wrong in here? if i insert `return` at the start of the functions it returns value.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function is called when the query has finished, which is likely to be after add_access() has already returned.

If you want to do anything with the query result, you have to do it in the callback function, or a function called from there.

Something like this:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT ...', [...],
              function (tx, results) {
                  alert(results.rows.length);
                  // ...
              });
```

Comment: Not working I tried calling it in a different function but didn't worked.
And how can I do callback?

Comment: I want the length returned in different function something like this
`var len=add_access_db.add_access(id, table); ` should hold the value returned instead its giving undefined.